# iOS How to decode a string encoded with NSWindowsCP1251

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, encoding

Please help me.
I have this code to get needed string to send to sever from normal readable string

```
- (NSString *)hexForWindowsCP1251 //"Привет"
{
   size_t theLength = strlen([self cStringUsingEncoding:NSWindowsCP1251StringEncoding]);

   const char *selfChar = [self cStringUsingEncoding:NSWindowsCP1251StringEncoding];

   NSData *stringData = [NSData dataWithBytes:selfChar length:theLength];

   NSString * hexStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", stringData];

   for(NSString * toRemove in [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"<", @">", @" ", nil])
   {
      hexStr = [hexStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:toRemove withString:@""];
   }

   return hexStr; //cff0e8e2e5f2      
 }
```

It`s all right as for English and for Russian text   (I get string like  "12e314f4"  )

What I don`t get is how to get the readable text fron such string.

For example string  "Привет"(hello in Russian) becomes  "cff0e8e2e5f2"

I need vice versa to get string "Hello" (if was encoded from English) and "Привет" (if was encoded from Russian)...

Answer (score 0):

I`ve finally got the work flow of converting to hex string and back.

These 3 methods are implemented in NSString Category:

```
 //To get hexEncoded string to pass to server:
- (NSString *)hexForWindowsCP1251
{
    size_t theLength = strlen([self cStringUsingEncoding:NSWindowsCP1251StringEncoding]);

    const char *selfChar = [self cStringUsingEncoding:NSWindowsCP1251StringEncoding];
    // \xef\xf0\xe8
    NSData *stringData = [NSData dataWithBytes:selfChar length:theLength];

    NSString * hexStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", stringData];

    for(NSString * toRemove in [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"<", @">", @" ", nil])
    {
        hexStr = [hexStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:toRemove withString:@""];
    }

    return hexStr;
}


//To make the string readable


- (NSString *)hexToStringNSWIndows1251
{
    NSData *bytes = [self dataFromHexString];

    NSString *toReturn = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:bytes encoding:NSWindowsCP1251StringEncoding];
    return toReturn;
}
- (NSData *)dataFromHexString
    {
        const char *chars = [self UTF8String];
        int i = 0, len = self.length;

        NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData dataWithCapacity:len / 2];
        char byteChars[3] = {'\0','\0','\0'};
        unsigned long wholeByte;

        while (i < len) {
            byteChars[0] = chars[i++];
            byteChars[1] = chars[i++];
            wholeByte = strtoul(byteChars, NULL, 16);
            [data appendBytes:&wholeByte length:1];
        }

        return data;
    }
```